# Execute VBScript from ssh (cygwin). Permission denied: 'CreateObject'

Tags: ssh, vbscript, cygwin

I'm using a VBScript to convert remotely a file from docx to pdf but I have problems with Window's permissions. I think the ssh user on cygwin sshd server has not administrator permission.

This is the error that the system show me.

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Permission denied: 'CreateObject'

If I try to execute the script locally then everything works fine.

How can I config the ssh user on cygwin to execute the script as administrator?

I looked on google but I did not find anything.

Thank you

Comment: Stackoverflow is for software development questions. Configuring ssh permissions on a windows server isn't really on topic. If you're looking for a way to change your script, you should edit your question to include your code.

Answer (score 1):

Would need more information on your environment, but here are some things that will help you resolve your issue.

- Check what user is running the cygwin service. You can make it administrator or give the user more permissions(I recommend the later)
- Use Process monitor to see what user is trying to execute the statement and give that user permissions.
- Give the COM Object you are trying to call, Read+Execute permissions for Everyone or just the user running the script.